# Incorrect neural network schema in training output

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm training a model in Azure ML Studio and the Net# specification I'm using doesn't match the NET# specification in the training output.

Here's my experiment - [image]

and here are my NN params -

[image]

and finally here is the NET# specification in the Hyperparams output -

[image]
It's not using two hidden layers and it's also using sigmoid instead of ReLu. Is this expected behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: I've found a post on the Azure ML forums about the same issue - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/de295295-b664-4b17-91f2-6e62c41dd664/custom-neural-network-parameter-sweep?forum=MachineLearning. The advice is to email someone at MS, which I've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with using custom NET# and parameter sweeps together: it switches over to using the default fully connected topology.

Unfortunately, the workaround is to train the model for each parameter value separately.

-Roope